# Replace logo.svg in default.xml not working Magento2

Tags: theme, magento-2.0.7, logo

OK, so I want to change the logo.svg with my own logo which is .jpg file (should be supported by Magento 2.0.7)
Created my new theme with all directories and files, selected the theme in the admin page.
Theme is working and but still using the logo.svg so far:
[image]

Now I added my logo under the web/images folder and made the following change to the default.xml under Magento_theme/layout which is in my theme folder (/app/design/frontend/espressoplaza/standaardep/Magento_theme/layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper"   htmlTag="div" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
    <arguments>
    <argument name="logo_file"  xsi:type="string">images/testlogo480x170.jpg</argument>
    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">480</argument>
    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">170</argument>
</arguments>
</referenceBlock>
        <move element="header.panel" destination="header.panel.wrapper"/>
```

I cleared all static content per script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -R ~/public_html/pub/static/frontend/
rm -R ~/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/
rm -R ~/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/source/frontend/
rm -R ~/public_html/var/cache
rm -R ~/public_html/var/generation
```

And cleaned the cache.
Still Magento is picking up the logo.svg from Blanc

What am I overlooking or doing wrong here.....

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 5):

Try to set a new argument in the `xml` for the `logo` block something like:

```
<referenceBlock name="logo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">147</argument>
        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">103</argument>
        <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">your_logo.img</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems **logo_src** argument should work, as [Vlad Patru](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/42971/vlad-patru) pointed https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/217677/3566

**Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo**

```
/**
 * Get logo image URL
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLogoSrc()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['logo_src'])) {
        $this->_data['logo_src'] = $this->_getLogoUrl();
    }
    return $this->_data['logo_src'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your image inside

`mytheme\web\images\logo.svg`

Then Run the below Command

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

then try

Comment: Thanks for reply, does your solution implies I can only use an image of the svg format? I understood Magento also supports jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Upload logo from admin panel from given below path (for magento 2.1.0 version):-

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration -> applied-theme -> Header - > Logo Image
```

And you can upload your logo image here jpg/png/gif format.

- save and clear cache.

> php bin/magento c:f

Comment: Thanks for  your reply, I am familiar with this way to change the logo, however from a learning perspective I am trying to find out why the default.xml doesnt do the trick for me....