# Logo not showing up in Magento 2.3 custom theme

Tags: magento2.3, custom-theme, logo

I have specified a custom logo in `<custom-theme-dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` as so, and uploaded the logo image file to `<custom-theme-dir>/web/images/theme_logo.png`, but the logo does not show up on the front end:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_src" xsi:type="string">images/theme_logo.png</argument>
            <argument name="logo_width" xsi:type="number">210</argument>
            <argument name="logo_height" xsi:type="number">30</argument>
            <argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">My Theme Co.</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

**The other parameters (width, height, alt text, etc. all show up in the image tag, but the source stays exactly as specified in default.xml.**

Other sites I've worked with make a replacement in the image source attribute pointing to the static file location, but for some reason, this "conversion" in the src path is not happening.

**What I'm seeing in the page source code:**

`<img src="*images/theme_logo.png*" title="My Theme Co." alt="My Theme Co." width="210" height="30">`

**What I expect to see:**

`<img src="*https://example.com/static/versionXXXXXXXXXXX/frontend/<Vendor>/<custom-theme-dir>/en_US/images/theme_logo.png*" title="My Theme Co." alt="My Theme Co." width="210" height="30">`

I've tried blowing away the static content, changing from developer mode to production mode and default mode, etc. and completely re-caching everything, re-indexing, etc. and there is no change. The logo does not show up because it seems that the logo file is not being transferred over to the static content.

**Why is this likely not happening?**

I've consulted several resources including:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html#theme_logo

[Replace logo.svg in default.xml not working Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138831/replace-logo-svg-in-default-xml-not-working-magento2?rq=1)

[store logo in not loading](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307040/store-logo-in-not-loading?noredirect=1#comment445864_307040)

Comment: Upload logo from magento backend , theme,  html , logo upload.

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm having the exact same problem

Comment: @BETSCH See Sam Tyler's answer below. Did the trick for me. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument needs to be `logo_file` instead of `logo_src`. So the whole line would be:

```xml
<argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/theme_logo.png</argument>
```

#### Notes:

The [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html#theme_logo) is incorrect as of the time of writing. There's a [PR](https://github.com/magento/devdocs/pull/7275) to fix it.

**Edit**: The PR is accepted and the documentation is now correct.